# New Zealand citizen who has been living in Korea a year, do I need a TB check to enter the UK?

Tags: visas, uk, new-zealand-citizens

So far I have found slightly conflicting information regarding whether I need a visa or not. New Zealanders **ARE NOT** required to get a TB check, however I have been living in South Korea for almost a year and their citizens **ARE** required to get a check. Of the information I have found so far...

The official UK Visa site says this:

"Who doesn’t need to be tested - You won’t need a TB test if any of the following apply:

•you’re a diplomat accredited to the UK

•you’re a returning UK resident and haven’t been away for more than 2 years

•you lived for at least 6 months in a country where TB screening is not required by the UK, and you’ve been away from that country for no more than 6 months"

Which isn't exactly clear in my case.
Another site I found said this:

"If you are apply for a visa for the UK that is for longer than 6 months then you will need to have a tuberculosis (TB) test done if you are coming to the UK and are a **resident** in any of these listed countries below."

Please clarify for me. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you will need to get a check.  South Korea [is a listed country](https://www.gov.uk/tb-test-visa/overview).

You have been living in South Korea for a year which essentially makes you a resident of that country, *and* you have been away from NZ for more than 6 months.

Note you only need this test if you are planning to stay in the UK for more than 6 months.